# Implementing Node store function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I was asked this question on implementing a store in ES5 and ES6.

I've been trying to solve this problem but I got stuck on how do I store the node

Implementing Store Class:

> Implement a store class with set(Node, value ), get(Node) and
>   has(Node) methods, which stores given Nodes with corresponding values.

This is what I was able to write (Pseudo-code)

```
function Store () {
    this.store = [];
}

Store.prototype.set = function(node, v) {
    // Problem here would be how do I store the node?
}

Store.prototype.get = function(node) {
    if(this.has(node)) {
        return this.store.find(each => {
            // Check to see if it's the same node and return.
        })
    }
}

Store.prototype.has = function(node) {
    return this.store.indexOf(node) > -1;
}
```

***NOTE: WE could be storing a HTML DOM in the store. So key would be a "DOM" element NOT a string.***

**Can someone enlighten me with an example? I would imagine this would work like a Map in ES6. How do I store the DOM node in the first place if i were to implement this in ES5?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the ES5 days it was common to create an array of keys and locate them with linear search. This isn't the most efficient solution, but simple.

```js
function Store() {
    this.keys = [];
    this.values = [];
}

Store.prototype.set = function(key, val) {
    var i = this.keys.indexOf(key);
    if(i < 0) {
        i = this.keys.push(key) - 1;
    }
    this.values[i] = val;
};

Store.prototype.get = function(key) {
    return this.values[this.keys.indexOf(key)];
};

Store.prototype.has = function(key) {
    return this.keys.indexOf(key) >= 0;
};

//

a = document.querySelector("#a")
b = document.querySelector("#b")
c = document.querySelector("#c")

s = new Store()

s.set(a, '1')
s.set(b, '2')

console.log(s.has(a), s.get(a))
console.log(s.has(b), s.get(b))
console.log(s.has(c), s.get(c))
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

There are two problems with this solution: first, the slow linear search, second, and more important, since the Store retains references to key objects, they cannot be garbage collected once destroyed.

A more efficient option is to inject the key into values themselves, but this is much trickier to implement.

For the ES6 part, there's a dedicated built-in object for this kind of thing, called [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap).

Comment: you are unnecessarily complicating the solution by having keys and values. You could just use an object and use it like a hashmap.

Comment: Well, the thing is , what if the key is a HTMLDOM node? Linear search wouldn't work directly out of the box? (Comparing two DOM's) 

This is where I've had issues with to see if i need to serialize it?

Comment: @TechnoCorner As long as it's the same node it would work. If you want two different nodes to be considered equal that is a different question.

Comment: Thanks for answering but sorry I don't quite get your comment. Let's imagine I am storing a HTMLDOM node (By using `set`) and I will try to use `get` to retrieve DOM Node. How do we retrieve DOM node? (This is as good as doing a linear scan and comparing two DOM's to see if they are equal. i.e deep nested comparison)

Comment: @TechnoCorner That's a weird definition of equality for DOM nodes. Usually you would just consider a node to be equal with itself, not to another node that has the same subtree structure but is somewhere else in the DOM. georg's answer will work for E.G. `console.log(s.has(document.getElementById('b')));` because it's the same node as the one that was put in.

Comment: Thanks. Great stuff. I think it will work because it's not nested. What if my node is nested? For example: key: `<div id="a"><div id="b"> </div></div>` And we . are trying to compare `<div id="a"><div id="b"><div id="c"> </div></div></div>`

It should obviously return false in this case.. Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm just trying to learn here. Appreciate all your responses

Comment: This is the solution I saw with ES6. He author wrapped this in another class `(CachedNode)`: https://codepen.io/rdabbir/pen/BEdjMv?editors=0010

Comment: @TechnoCorner Nesting doesn't make any difference. If you have `<div id="a"><div id="b"><div id="c"> </div></div></div>` and you put `a` into the store then `get(document.getElementById('a'))` will work properly. If you have another node somewhere else with the exact same structure it won't be found in the store because it's not the same node. The store only checks if it has that node already, it doesn't care what type of node it is or whether it has any children or not.

Comment: This does the same thing as that ES6 solution, but that ES6 solution is unnecessary because you could just use a Map in ES6.

Comment: Got it. This is great learning experience for me. Thank you and @georg for enlightening me!

Answer (score 0):

If nodes are mutable, we can try to create and assign each node its unique ID:

```js
function NodeStore() {
  this.nodesValueMap = {};
  this.lastId = 0;
}

NodeStore.prototype.set = function(node, value) {
  // text nodes do not have dataset (DOMStringMap), create simple object
  node.dataset = node.dataset || {};
  node.dataset.uniqueId = node.dataset.uniqueId || ++this.lastId;
  this.nodesValueMap[node.dataset.uniqueId] = value;
}

NodeStore.prototype.get = function(node) {
  return node.dataset.uniqueId && this.nodesValueMap[node.dataset.uniqueId];
}

NodeStore.prototype.has = function(node) {
  return !!(node.dataset.uniqueId && this.nodesValueMap[node.dataset.uniqueId]);
}

var textNode = document.querySelector("#a").childNodes[0];
var b = document.querySelector("#b");
var c = document.querySelector("#c");

var store = new NodeStore();

store.set(textNode, '1');
store.set(b, '2');

console.log(store.has(textNode), store.get(textNode));
console.log(store.has(b), store.get(b));
console.log(store.has(c), store.get(c));
```

```html
<div id="a">asdf</div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

all methods will run now in complexity of O(1).

It is not necessary to use `dataset`, we could write the unique ID on the node itself.

Another thing is, that we may have IDs collisions in case of multiple stores at the same page, where each store may mutate the same property at the same node. To solve this, we could add some unique to current instance of store ***salt***, which could be passed for example via constructor and then used to prefix or suffix `uniqueId`.

Answer (score 0):

Since we talking about storing nodes, we can make use of `dataset`

```
class NodeStore {
      constructor() {
        this.store = {};
        this.id = 1;
      }
       /**
       * @param {Node} node
       * @param {any} value
       */
      set(node, value) {
        const id = node.dataset.storeid || this.id++;
        this.store[id] = value; 
        node.dataset.storeid = id;
      }
      /**
       * @param {Node} node
       * @return {any}
       */
      get(node) {
       const { storeid } = node.dataset;
       return this.store[storeid];
      }
      
      /**
       * @param {Node} node
       * @return {Boolean}
       */
      has(node) {
        const { storeid } = node.dataset;
        return storeid in this.store;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
function Store () {
    this.store = {};
}

Store.prototype.set = function(node, v) {
    this.store[node] = v;
}

Store.prototype.get = function(node) {
    return this.store[node];
}

Store.prototype.has = function(node) {
    return this.store[node] !== undefined
}
```

Comment: You may want to implement `has` as `return node in this.store;` instead so that storing `undefined` as a value doesn't break `has`.

Comment: Well, I know this but the question would be how would you store a "DOM" node in an object as the key.. Because Objects only accept "string" as the key if i'm not wrong.

Comment: @TechnoCorner Yes, this would only work with strings or Symbols (but they're not part of ES5).

Comment: The question I was actually trying to solve was for a HTMDOM node. How would I store it in the object? and while retrieving how do you compare two DOM's?

Answer (score -3):

Store it like Objects inside Objects that may work for your case I think.

First `this.store` will be

```
this.store = {}
```

Then, in set function you can do

```
this.store[node] = value;
```

and in your get,

```
return this.store[node]
```

This is pretty simple and straight forward I think

**Update**: 
If you want to take DOM has key : Stringify the DOM and take it as key and store value as you want.

Comment: You can only store "strings" in an object as key. You can't store a "DOM" node as the key my friend. So this solution won't scale for a HTMLDOM node(s)

Comment: How big is your DOM element, if it is just simple DOM with not many children. I prefer stringify DOM and store it as key. I know this is not ideal, but may be a workaroud for this problem